# How to use soft assertions to avoid test run execution to fail

Tags: java, debugging, selenium-webdriver, testng, assert

I want to continue test run execution even the one or more assertions get fails in `TestNG`.

I referred below links in order to implement `soft assertion` in my project.

http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/

http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/

http://www.seleniumtests.com/2008/09/soft-assertion-is-check-which-doesnt.html

But I'm not understanding the flow of code execution, like function calls, `FLOW`.

Kindly help me to understand the work flow of the `soft assertions`.

Code:

```
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
    import org.testng.asserts.IAssert; 
    
    //Implementation Of Soft Assertion 
    public class SoftAssertions extends Assertion{   
    @Override public void executeAssert(IAssert a){ 
    try{ a.doAssert(); } 
    catch(AssertionError ex){ 
    System.out.println(a.getMessage()); } } } 
    
    //Calling Soft Assertion
 SoftAssertions sa = new SoftAssertions(); 
 sa.assertTrue(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle),
"Login Success, But Uname and Pwd are wrong");
```

**Note:**

Execution Continues even though above assertion fails

Comment: Can you show us your code? What did you try? What did you expect? What happened instead?

Comment: Well, 
Code is as below.
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion; 
import org.testng.asserts.IAssert; 
//Implementation Of Soft Assertion
 public class SoftAssertions extends Assertion{ 
 @Override
 public void executeAssert(IAssert a){
 try{ 
a.doAssert(); }
catch(AssertionError ex){ 
System.out.println(a.getMessage()); 
} } }

 //Calling Soft Assertion
SoftAssertions softAssertions = new SoftAssertions(); softAssertions.assertTrue(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle), "Login Successful Eventhough Username and Password Is Wrong");

Execution Continues even though above assertion fails

Comment: That's your code, but what output did you expect and what output did you get instead? Where does your mis-understanding of soft assertions come from?

Comment: I called assertTrue() method of SoftAssertion, but in soft assertion i dont have assertTrue() method, instead i have overhidden "ExecuteAssert()" methos which internally calling doAssert(). 
So how this flow is happening...?

Comment: Since your `SoftAssertions` extends `Assertion` your class inherits all method that `Assertion` contains. I believe you are supposed to run something like `sa.assertAll()` at the end of your test in order for the test to "fail".

Answer (score 3):

Soft assertions work by storing the failure in local state (maybe logging them to `stderr` as they are encountered). When the test is finished it needs to check for any stored failures and, if any were encountered, fail the entire test at that point.

I believe what the maintainer of TestNG had in mind was a call to `myAssertion.assertAll()` at the end of the test which will run `Assert.fail()` and make the test fail if any previous soft-assertion checks failed.

You can make this happen yourself by adding a `@Before` method to initialize your local soft-assertion object, use it in your test and add an `@After` method to run the `assertAll()` method on your soft-assertion object.

Be aware that this `@Before`/`@After` approach makes your test non-thread-safe so each test must be run within a new instance of your test class. Creating your soft-assertion object inside the test method itself and running the `assertAll()` check at the end of the method is preferable if your test needs to be thread-safe. One of the cool features of TestNG is its ability to run multi-threaded tests, so be aware of that as you implement these soft-asserts.

Comment: For an example of an abstract class to handle soft assertions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25068860/2167531