# Can we handle Assert fail in try and catch in testNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assert

I am trying to automate application using selenium webDriver + TestNG.

In which I am using multiple assert statement like
    Assert.assertEquals("Dhaval", "Dhaval1");

and I am trying to catch the assertionfail exception using try& catch block.
as i am filling up an excell sheet for test result .

But any how while assertion fails application direct stop execution and catch block is will not execute.

Any suggestion.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: You probably need to post a sample of the code in question + the exception text you are receiving.

Comment: You question is hard to understand but I think that you are looking for is a soft assert. An assert that doesn't cause the test to immediately stop and fail. See if this helps... note the link in the answer comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091526/how-soft-assertions-work

Comment: Josh - it's a simple question that what to do if I don't want to stop execution the automated script if assertion fails...

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching exceptions on test assertions is a bad practice, they are asserts for a reason.
What you want to do is implement custom `ITestListener` and define required logic in `onTestFailure(ITestResult result)` method, code in this method will be executed if case will fail.

Comment: how do you pass values to onTestFailure( ... ) in order to provide additional information as to why the assertion failed?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try {
Assert.assertEquals("Dhaval", "Dhaval1");
}
catch (AssertionError e) {
Assert.assertEquals("Dhaval", "Dhaval");
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question and what is this supposed to do? You eat one exception and then log a pass when it actually failed?

Comment: Yes bcoz I am not using testNG report for final test result ,

Comment: I have done the testrail integration direct with my selenum code and after each test method it will insert the result in testrail so for that this is the answer of my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling the tests results inside the test methods to save it to the spreadsheet, you are doing a bad practice. Take a look here to void this: http://www.techbeamers.com/save-selenium-webdriver-testng-result-excel/

Else, if you really need to do this:

```
try {
    Assert.assertNotEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Thread the excpetion here
}
```